# Use of passive verb in "Echō iuvenem sēcrētō sequitur"

Tags: verbs, conjugation

In chapter XIII of Latin Via Ovid, the authors have the following sentences (bolding is mine):

> Ōlim Narcissus cum cēteris iuvenibus animālia fera in silvīs et montibus sequitur. Forte sōlus errat, et **Echō iuvenem sēcrētō sequitur**.

Why is *iuvenis* accusative in this sentence? With the passive verb, I would have expected it to also be nominative, i.e. "the youth is secretely followed by Echō".

Answer (score 6):

*sequī* is a **deponent** verb meaning 'to follow', it's passive in form but otherwise active. A dead giveaway for this fact is the absence of any *ā* + abl. 'by' construction which could express the agent which in an active construction would stand in the nominative. The actor here is, of course, *Ēchō* who is in the nominative and is a female. If it was in the ablative, the nominative would have to be some masculine **Ēchus;* as importantly, a bare ablative cannot express the agent at all, only the instrument.

The same verb is used in the previous sentence and the same observation on the absence of any potential passive agents applies.

Answer (score 6):

The verb *sequi* is a **deponent verb**.
It means that it has passive forms and active meaning.
(This may not be the whole story, but this is the best starting point to understanding deponent verbs.)
Despite the looks, *sequitur* means "he/she/it follows", not "is followed".

The verb *sequi* takes an accusative object like many other verbs.
The only difference is that it appears passive, but in meaning it is not.
There is no such form as *<del>sequit</del>* or any other active form (apart from participles).

If this were a true passive sentence, then the personal agent (here *Echo*) should come with the preposition *a(b(s))* and be in the ablative case.